# is not a recognized storage provider (Mongoid, Carrierwave and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, carrierwave

i'm using Carrierwave with mongoid support

```
gem "carrierwave-mongoid", :git => "git://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid.git", :branch => "mongoid-3.0",:require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
```

I config carrierwave to use Fog storage with AWS (S3)

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :fog
    config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
    config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' # ...two lines
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id => '',
        :aws_secret_access_key => ''
    },
    config.fog_directory = 'alzheimer'
end
```

I have a class called Picture to use with the Uploader and the uploader

```
class ImagenUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
    include CarrierWave::RMagick
    storage :fog
    process :set_content_type
    process :convert => 'png'
    def filename
        super.chomp(File.extname(super))+'.png'
    end
    version :thumb do
        process :resize_to_fit => [24,24]
    end
end
```

And my Picture Model
    class Picture
         include Mongoid::Document
         include Mongoid::Timestamps
         include Mongoid::Paranoia
         belongs_to :user

```
     field :descripcion, :type => String
     field :titulo, :type => String
     field :imagen, :type => String

     attr_accessible :imagen, :imagen_cache, :descripcion, :titulo
     mount_uploader :imagen, ImagenUploader
 end
```

I try to upload an image, ad i get:

```
ArgumentError: is not a recognized storage provider
from /Users/msdark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/fog-1.5.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:33:in new'
from /Users/msdark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:106:inconnection'
```

I use rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p194
and unicorn (4.3.1)

The error shows up after upload when try to show this:

```
image_tag(picture.imagen_url)
```

Any idea?

EDITED:

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
   gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
   gem 'jquery-rails'
   gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
   gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
end

gem 'unicorn'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'foreman'

gem 'i18n'
gem 'formtastic'
gem "activeadmin-mongoid",  git: "git://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid.git"
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem "carrierwave-mongoid", :git => "git://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid.git", :branch => "mongoid-3.0", :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'mini_magick', :git => 'git://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick.git'

gem 'recaptcha',            :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'googlecharts'

group :test do 
gem 'capybara'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'mongoid-rspec'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'mongoid-rspec'
gem 'faker'
end 
gem 'rspec-rails',:group =>[:development,:test]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It turns out my uploader didn't have a storage engine that matched with what was defined in the config. I did a pry inside of the Carrierwave config (in the initializer) and looked at the storage_engines.

```
[5] pry(main)> config.storage_engines
=> {:file=>"CarrierWave::Storage::File", :fog=>"CarrierWave::Storage::Fog"}
```

Then I made sure that the uploader's setting matched one of the entries in here. So in your case, if you have

```
class ImagenUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...
  storage :fog
  ...
end
```

then you need to make sure that there is an entry for `:fog` in the config context that your working with. You can backtrack from there.

I realize this is a slightly older question, but if you haven't figured it out, I hope that helps.

Comment: where is this `config` coming from in your pry console?